# SyntaxError: missing { before function body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get our website up and running.

I installed a plugin for a slideshow, which then stopped the page's form automatically refreshing when closing the slideshow. After a lot of research, I put in this code to the jquery.easing.1.3.js

Now, I am able to get an automatic refresh, but my menu doesn't work.

The new error using Firefox says:

> SyntaxError: missing { before function body

However, in Chrome, it says:

> Unexpected token .

The website is:  www.harmandisplay.com

The code in jquery.easing.1.3.js:

```
// t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
jQuery.easing['jswing'] = jQuery.easing['swing'];

jQuery.extend( jQuery.easing,
{ 
$(document).ready{(function(): {
    def: 'easeOutQuad',
    swing: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        //alert(jQuery.easing.default);
        return jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def](x, t, b, c, d);
    },
    easeInQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c*(t/=d)*t + b;
    },
    easeOutQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return -c *(t/=d)*(t-2) + b;
    },
```

.... and it goes on and on.

Comment: `$(document).ready{...` pretty sure you don't want the `{` there.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
$(document).ready{(function(): {
```

is a syntax error

remove the `':'`

Comment: explain how `$(document).ready{(function()` fits into `$.extend`? You are removing the wrong part

Answer (score 0):

You have an invalid `:` syntax that is breaking the JavaScript code. Change

```
$(document).ready{(function(): {
```

To

```
$(document).ready{(function() {
```